# Sort an array without using loops in java

Tags: arrays

How to get second maximum value from array without using nested loops in java? 
For eg: int [] arr = {2,4,1,6,5,9,0,7}
        Output : 7

Comment: Just posted an answer to the question "sort an array without using loops", but have deleted it as I realise that's not actually what you're asking.  Might be sensible to update the question title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
...
Arrays.sort(arr);
result = arr[arr.length - 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (arr.length > 1)
{
    Collections.Arrays.sort(arr);
    int secondMax = arr[arr.length - 2];
}
```

[Inspired by this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828091/how-to-get-the-minimum-maximum-value-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array sort method easily.

```
int [] arr = {2,4,1,6,5,9,0,7};
Arrays.sort(arr);
System.out.println(arr[arr.length - 2]);
```